# Find all possible combination of numbers from a string of number while maintaining the original order

Tags: algorithm, search, combinations

Say if you have string: 1234

What I need is to generate all possible number combinations from this string, but the **original order of the string must be maintained**.

Also there must be **at least 2 numbers** in each result.

In the case of 1234 the output would be an list of lists

output list:

```
list: 1, 2, 3, 4
list: 12, 3, 4
list: 123, 4        --Note a list containing only 1234 is not valid
list: 1, 23, 4
list: 1, 234
list: 1, 2, 34
list: 12, 34
```

Also note that the numbers in each of the result list is always ordered the same way as the original string 1234. So a list with combination 34, 21 or 213, 4 is not valid.

The only approach I can think of:

1. Start at the 1st index (1)
2. Append the next number to form a new number(12)
3. Then recursively pass in the newly formed number to append the next number (123)
4. After the 1st index is done, we start all over again with the second index (2)
5. ...

However with my approach I don't know how I can generate the 12, 34 combination

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try to think in these terms: I already have the answer for 234..n, how do I transform it into the answer for 1234..n?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5
  |   |   |   |
  d1  d2  d3  d4
```

Suppose the origin string has length 5, and we divide this string by adding a divider d1, d2 ,d3 and d4 which can be empty.

- when d1, d2 ,d3 ,d4 are **all** empty, we get `12345`.
- when d2, d3, d4 are empty, we get `1, 2345`
- when **none of d1, d2, d3, d4** are empty, we get `1,2,3,4,5`

for every divider we added, it has two options: visible or gone,
so the total possible count is `2^(n-1) - 1` when n is the length of the original string

Then, the next problem we will solve is to iterate all the possibilities:
use a binary value to represent the divider:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= pow(2, n - 1); i++) {
     // i = 1, 0b0001, d4 is visible, we get 1234,5
     // i = 2, 0b0010, d3 is visible, we get 123,45
     // i = 3, 0b0011, d3 and d4 is visible, we get 123,4,5
     // i = 4, 0b0100, d2 is visible, we get 12,345
     // i = 5, 0b0101, d2 and d4 is visible, we get 12, 34, 5
     // i = 6, 0b0110, d2 and d3 is visible, we get 12, 3, 45
     // i = 7, 0b0111, d2,d3,d4 is visible, we get 12,3,4,5
     // go on...
}
```

Hope help...

Answer (score 0):

You can use similar approach to get the output you need.
Modify it as it is simple traversing.

```
String str="1234";
    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder(str);
    int l=str.length();
    for(int i=0;i<l;i++){
        int j=i+1;
        if(i!=0)
            j=i+2;
        for(;j<l+1;j++){
            sb.insert(j, ',');
            System.out.println(sb);
            sb.deleteCharAt(j);
        }
        sb=new StringBuilder(str);
        sb.insert(i+1, ',');
    }
```

It produces the following output

```
1,234
12,34
123,4
1234,
1,2,34
1,23,4
12,3,4
```